# I want to select duplicate rows between 2 dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to filter rolls (`df1`) with date column that in `datetime64[ns]` from `df2` (same column name and dtype). I tried searching for a solution but I get the error:

> Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects | 'Timestamp' object is not iterable or other.

sample df1

| id | date | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2018-10-09 | 120 |
| 2 | 2018-10-09 | 60 |
| 3 | 2018-10-10 | 59 |
| 4 | 2018-11-25 | 120 |
| 5 | 2018-08-25 | 120 |

sample df2

| date |
| --- |
| 2018-10-09 |
| 2018-10-10 |

sample result that I want

| id | date | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2018-10-09 | 120 |
| 2 | 2018-10-09 | 60 |
| 3 | 2018-10-10 | 59 |

In fact, I want this program to run 1 time in every 7 days, counting back from the day it started. So I want it to remove dates that are not in these past 7 days.

```
# create new dataframe -> df2
data = {'date':[]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data)

#Set the date to the last 7 days.
days_use = 7 # 7 -> 1
for x in range (days_use,0,-1):
    days_use = x
    use_day = date.today() - timedelta(days=days_use)
    df2.loc[x] = use_day

#Change to datetime64[ns]
df2['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['date'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `isin`:

```
>>> df1[df1["date"].isin(df2["date"])]
   id        date  value
0   1  2018-10-09    120
1   2  2018-10-09     60
2   3  2018-10-10     59
```

If you want to create `df2` with the dates for the past week, you can simply use `pd.date_range`:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"date": pd.date_range(pd.Timestamp.today().date()-pd.DateOffset(7),periods=7)})

>>> df2
        date
0 2022-05-03
1 2022-05-04
2 2022-05-05
3 2022-05-06
4 2022-05-07
5 2022-05-08
6 2022-05-09
```